# How to add Azure Digital Twins Data Owner Role via Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-digital-twins

Using the Azure Python SDK, I have been able to instantiate a resource group and a digital twin within using the following code:

```py
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential, DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

from azure.mgmt.digitaltwins import AzureDigitalTwinsManagementClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id="some UUID" # not sure if safe to reveal, so removed it

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credential, subscription_id=subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "Tutorial-RG"
rg_result = resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name, {"location": "westeurope"}
)


client = AzureDigitalTwinsManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
)

dt_resource_name = "myDigitalTwinsService"
response = client.digital_twins.begin_create_or_update(
    resource_group_name=rg_result.name,
    resource_name = dt_resource_name,
    digital_twins_create={"location": "westeurope"},
).result()
print(response)


# ...
# 'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded',
# ...
```

I know that I need to add the 'Azure Digital Twins Data Owner' role before being able to manipulate it using the Azure Digital Twins Python SDK. I can do that using the Azure CLI as follows:

```bash
>>> az dt role-assignment create --dt-name myDigitalTwinsService --assignee "my UUID" --role "Azure Digital Twins Data Owner" --debug
```

But I am unable to add the same role using the Azure Authorization Management Client. So far I have tried the code below:

```py
from azure.mgmt.authorization.models import RoleAssignmentCreateParameters
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient

authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
)

adt_data_owner_role_id ='bcd981a7-7f74-457b-83e1-cceb9e632ffe'
role_def_id = f'/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/{adt_data_owner_role_id}'
authorization_client.role_assignments.create(
    scope=SCOPE,
    role_assignment_name=f"/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/Tutorial-RG/providers/Microsoft.DigitalTwins/digitalTwinsInstances/myDigitalTwinsService/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/60252f13-5e5a-4686-8265-3ac2db6443f1",
    parameters=RoleAssignmentCreateParameters(
        role_definition_id= role_def_id,
        principal_id= 'my UUID',
        principal_type="User",
    )
)
```

I have taken the parameters from the `az` call mentioned above by passing the `--debug` flag.
But I get the following error:

```
HttpResponseError: (NoRegisteredProviderFound) No registered resource provider found for location 'westeurope' and API version '2022-04-01' for type 'digitalTwinsInstances'. The supported api-versions are '2023-01-31, 2022-10-31, 2022-05-31, 2021-06-30-preview, 2020-12-01, 2020-10-31, 2020-03-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'westcentralus, westus2, northeurope, australiaeast, westeurope, eastus, southcentralus, southeastasia, uksouth, eastus2, westus3, japaneast, koreacentral, qatarcentral'.
Code: NoRegisteredProviderFound
Message: No registered resource provider found for location 'westeurope' and API version '2022-04-01' for type 'digitalTwinsInstances'. The supported api-versions are '2023-01-31, 2022-10-31, 2022-05-31, 2021-06-30-preview, 2020-12-01, 2020-10-31, 2020-03-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'westcentralus, westus2, northeurope, australiaeast, westeurope, eastus, southcentralus, southeastasia, uksouth, eastus2, westus3, japaneast, koreacentral, qatarcentral'.
```

Even changing the location to a supported region doesn't help despite the error message saying so.
When I change the api version, it doesn't work. I just get a different error:

```
authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    api_version = '2022-05-31'
)
# same everything else

# ValueError: API version 2022-05-31 does not have operation group 'role_assignments'
```

How do I fix this error? Or the action that I want to do is not supported by the Azure Python SDK at present ?

The versions of the azure SDK that I am using are as follows:
Generated using `pip list --format=freeze | grep azure`:

```
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.26.2
azure-digitaltwins-core==1.2.0
azure-identity==1.12.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==3.0.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
azure-mgmt-digitaltwins==6.4.0
azure-mgmt-resource==22.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python SDK code that worked for me to assign Azure Digital Twins Data Owner role to the user.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.authorization.models import RoleAssignmentCreateParameters
import uuid

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id="<Azure-Subscription-id>"

# Create a DigitalTwinsManagementClient instance
client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Define the parameters for the role assignment
role_assignment_params = RoleAssignmentCreateParameters(
    role_definition_id="/subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/bcd981a7-7f74-457b-83e1-cceb9e632ffe",
    principal_id="<Azure-user-object-id>"
)

# Create the role assignment
response = client.role_assignments.create(
    scope="/subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/IoTHubResources/providers/Microsoft.DigitalTwins/digitalTwinsInstances/<your-Azure-Digital-Twins-instance>",
    role_assignment_name=str(uuid.uuid4()),
    parameters=role_assignment_params
)
print(response)
```

> Please ensure to replace your Azure subscription id in variables subscription_id, role_definition_id and scope. Provide your Azure user id to the variable principal_id. Replace your-Azure-Digital-Twins-instance at the end of scope variable with your Azure Digital Twin instance name.

The versions of the azure SDK that I am using are as follows

```
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.26.3
azure-digitaltwins-core==1.2.0
azure-identity==1.12.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==3.0.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
azure-mgmt-digitaltwins==6.3.0
azure-mgmt-resource==22.0.0
```